# Is it possible to automatically buy (bind, alias) items in DotA 2's configurable 'recommended' area of the Shop?

Tags: dota-2

I know that it is possible to create an alias to buy things directly from the shop, as in:

```
dota_shop_force_hotkeys 1
toggleshoppanel
shop_nav_to_tab 1
shop_select_itemrow 2
```

And that's very nice. But is there any way to alias purchasing the suggested items on the configurable pane to the left? For example, it would be very nice if I could do:

```
dota_shop_force_hotkeys 1
toggleshoppanel
shop_custom_buy 1 1  // first (starter) section, first item
shop_custom_buy 1 2  // first section, second item
shop_custom_buy 1 3  // etc...
shop_custom_buy 1 4  
shop_custom_buy 1 5  
shop_custom_buy 1 6
shop_custom_buy 1 7
shop_custom_buy 1 8
```

This alias would just purchase the entire starter section with a single click. Obviously 'shop_custom_buy' is not the right command... what is?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53286/how-to-script-autobuy-of-specific-items

Comment: Actually, very specifically not a duplicate. I am asking about a different area of the shop. Did you not read the first paragraph of my question? That covers the 'possible duplicate' you mention.

Comment: There's a reason for referring to it as a **Possible** duplicate. No need to get upset.

Comment: i thought about this feature too. did not find anything to do that. but i created a script (basically suggested items) for each hero that gets the items out of the shop(as seen in my post). so numpad 7 gets me the startup items from the actual hero after i exec that "pudge.cfg" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a command for selecting the suggested items that can then be used in a script to bind the key.

After looking the other question over I mistook the 'columns' as a way to select the suggested items (I am a LoL player so yeah, suggested items go on the top right :D)

Anywho, here is the [Wiki for commands in Dota2](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Console_Command_List), the only thing that mentions suggested items that I saw was to show them or not which is:

> dota_shop_recommended_open